# CA certificates with SNI?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ca, sni

I want to use more than one SSL certificate on one single server. In the past that only was possible when you have more IPs pointing to it. Now I read about SNI which makes it possible to achieve just that, though it's only supported by actual browsers on the client side. I always read in the prerequisites for SNI that you need at least Apache version 2.2.12 and OpenSSL 0.9.8f.

So can I use certificates from Thawte, Verisign or other certificate authorities with this technique? These certificates aren't OpenSSL, are they?

Answer (score 1):

Server Name Indication is a mechanism for the client to tell the server which host name it's requesting, so that the server can choose which certificate to send to the client (if it has more than one). The issuer of the certificate doesn't matter.

The SNI extension must be supported by both the client and the server for this to work. This is why, if you're using an Apache Server with OpenSSL, you need versions that support it. Client-side support isn't limited to browsers (recent versions of cURL should support SNI too) and it varies depending on the browser/platform.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed OpenSSL as crypto library and certificates created using OpenSSL. SNI is about SSL, and certificates are NOT SSL - they are independent entity, often used by SSL.

For SNI to work you need to have a server and a client both support SNI. However it doesn't matter what certificates you use (or whether you use certificates at all).

Comment: Ah ok. So I need the OpenSSL library for the SSL connection and it has nothing to do with the creation of certificates?

Comment: @m0tv As you are going to purchase third-party certificates, you don't need to use OpenSSL for certificate generation (though technically OpenSSL includes functions to generate X.509 certificates).